# cached json error 503 for jarfile on JFrog Artifactory, but jar exists on remote repository Bintray

Tags: maven, artifactory

Why is my local artifactory server is caching this for a jarfile? (Artifactory version 4.2.0)

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 503,
    "message" : "Error fetching http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/querydsl/querydsl-sql/4.0.7/querydsl-sql-4.0.7.jar (remote response: 503: Service Unavailable)"
  } ]
}
```

If the remote repository has the jar [here](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/com.querydsl%3Aquerydsl-sql/view#files/com/querydsl/querydsl-sql/4.0.7), how can I get maven to re-download the jarfile?

When I inspect Artifactory, the cache tells me that it downloaded the jarfile a long time ago, which leads me to believe that it cached a version of the jar that didn't exist.

Why is my maven build failing with `Error 503` and telling me it can't find this 4.0.7 jarfile?

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building xyz Management Framework DAL DSL Codegen 1.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://artifactory.int.fusionio.com:8081/artifactory/repo/com/querydsl/querydsl-sql/4.0.7/querydsl-sql-4.0.7.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.057s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Jan 22 11:23:42 MST 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/481M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project sndk-jmx-dal-dsl-codegen: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.xyz.jmxsrv.service:sndk-jmx-dal-dsl-codegen:jar:1.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact com.querydsl:querydsl-sql:jar:4.0.7 from/to repo (http://artifactory.int.fusionio.com:8081/artifactory/repo): Failed to transfer file: http://artifactory.int.fusionio.com:8081/artifactory/repo/com/querydsl/querydsl-sql/4.0.7/querydsl-sql-4.0.7.jar. Return code is: 503 -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Artifactory caches errors from remote repos in order to speed up the builds (if a remote server is down we assume it will be down for five more minutes). Those caches can be zapped (and of course they are invalidated after 5 minutes).

If you want to rerun the build during this time, being logged in as Administrator right click on the root of `jcenter-cache` repo in the Artifacts tab, select "Zap Caches" and rerun the build.

Or just rerun the build after 5 minutes.

Comment: you could improve your answer by providing more context around the use of the 5 minute interval you mentioned.

Comment: I was in the completely wrong page in the GUI. Yes, you were totally right about reading the documentation. Could you please edit your answer so I can upvote it? You must log in as admin, and go to the "Artifacts" tab. Using the Actions or right-click menu, zap cache is an option

Comment: Edited. BTW, the phrase about admin was already there (re reading again).